# Magento 2: Log Error message on phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml, log

how can I print the log error message in the phtml file? the error can be shown to the user on the page

Comment: u need to print error in log file or on your frontend page?

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in anywhere in magento2 for print log :-

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info("Product Info ". $product->getSku());
```

**That Zend has been changed to Laminas so use below line after 2.3.5**

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
```

Comment: That Zend has been changed to $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log'); after 2.3.5

Comment: Right..answer updated

Answer (score 0):

If you are string output then try this code :

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()   
->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug('Your Message');
```

If you have array or something then try this code :

```
$myArray = array(........);
$level = '100'; 
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')
    ->log($level, print_r($myArray, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use catch and through blocks the error messaged thrown can be called in block and same can be shown to user

in phtml file
$block->getErrorMessage();

in block class

public getErrorMessage(){

return error message;
}